# Migrating to Google Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently using ga.js and I want to upgrade to the universal analytics.

Do I need to restate all my old ga calls to do that or is it backwards compatible.  The google documentation seems a big vague on this topic.

example of a ga call:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
```

I want to know how much re-work I have to do, or if I can just update standard js snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the new syntax with Universal Analytics (if applicable):

```
_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]); // ga('create', 'UA-XXX-Y', {'allowAnchor': true});
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); // ga('send', 'pageview');
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']); // This has been deprecated and is a default feature in UA
```

More info about page load timing can be found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings